# EF 5 LINQ joining tables with multiple conditions in ON clause

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to join tables using two conditions in my on clause but I get the error

> Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type byte and byte

How can I use multiple conditions in the ON clause for joining tables?

```
                    using (var db = new ReleaseInfo())
                {
                    lvReleaseInfo = (from r in db.ReleaseTranslations
                                     join c in db.Countries
                                     on r.SectionRelease.ReleaseCountryID equals c.CountryID && c.CultureID equals CultureID
                                     join pf in db.Platforms
                                     on r.SectionRelease.PlatformID equals pf.PlatformID && pf.PlatformID equals CultureID
                                     join pub in db.Publishers
                                     on r.SectionRelease.PublisherID equals pub.PublisherID && pub.CultureID equals CultureID
                                     where r.ReleaseID == SectionID && r.CultureID == CultureID
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an anonymous type for each side of the equi-join:

```
lvReleaseInfo = (from r in db.ReleaseTranslations
                 join c in db.Countries
                 on new {CountryID = r.SectionRelease.ReleaseCountryID, CultureID} equals new {c.CountryID, c.CultureID}
                 join pf in db.Platforms
                 on new {r.SectionRelease.PlatformID, CultureID} equals new {pf.PlatformID, CultureID = pf.PlatformID}
                 join pub in db.Publishers
                 on new {r.SectionRelease.PublisherID, r.CultureID} equals new {pub.PublisherID, pub.CultureID}
                 where r.ReleaseID == SectionID && r.CultureID == CultureID
```